# Android resource linking failed: fastforward_increment not found

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/markalarbirligi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bf604d02c1d803a3083f24e586de57ff/jetified-mobilertc/res/layout/activity_media_player.xml:7: AAPT: error: attribute fastforward_increment (aka com.ingilizcekursu.ingilizce_kursu:fastforward_increment) not found.

     /Users/markalarbirligi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bf604d02c1d803a3083f24e586de57ff/jetified-mobilertc/res/layout/activity_media_player.xml:7: AAPT: error: attribute rewind_increment (aka com.ingilizcekursu.ingilizce_kursu:rewind_increment) not found.

     /Users/markalarbirligi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bf604d02c1d803a3083f24e586de57ff/jetified-mobilertc/res/layout/zm_content_file_video_viewer.xml:8: AAPT: error: attribute fastforward_increment (aka com.ingilizcekursu.ingilizce_kursu:fastforward_increment) not found.

     /Users/markalarbirligi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bf604d02c1d803a3083f24e586de57ff/jetified-mobilertc/res/layout/zm_content_file_video_viewer.xml:8: AAPT: error: attribute rewind_increment (aka com.ingilizcekursu.ingilizce_kursu:rewind_increment) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I used flutter_zoom_sdk and video_player libraries together in my project.
Of course, I added the following code to the app/src/build.gradle file to use together.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.0'
}
```

How can i fix this error?
NOTE: I use flutter, not native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added versions of Exoplayer common to flutter_zoom_sdk and video_player libraries to pubspec.yaml .

My pubspec file:

[image]

Comment: how did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Bro I think you should leave just one implementation definition of exoplayer. Maybe the 2.17.0 version.

Comment: I tried but it keeps giving the same error.

Comment: Did you try flutter clean and flutter pub get commands after that? Sometimes Flutter caches these files like build.gradle.

Comment: I tried the following:
-flutter clean,
-flutter pub cache clean,
it's not working for me.